# Pass Value From JavaScript Function to Code Behind of ASPX Page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a JavaScript function to determine the screen size of the device (in which the site is being viewed). It will return int values like 0, 1 or 2 which I need to capture in the code behind of the aspx page.

I am aware about passing parameters to JavaScript from asp.net. But how do I do the reverse, that is pass value from the javascript function and accept it in the code behind?

Are hidden fields approach the only way?

Also, I heard from someone that I can have some variables in code behind and assign values to them through Ajax methods. If so, how to achieve via AJAX?

Comment: You can't directly, you can either set the value of a hidden field or similar which will be passed back when you do a postback or you can call a web service with the data if you don't want to do a postback.

Comment: What about AJAX? I heard from someone, that I can have some variables in code behind and assign values to them through Ajax methods.

Comment: That is what I mean by call a web service, you do this using AJAX.

Comment: @BenRobinson I am clueless with AJAX approach. Never done it. Could you give me some more leads?